# How to set uncategorized category as the default category for custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to set uncategorized category as the default category for custom post type in wordpress? I mean whenever new custom posts is added, the uncategorized category should get automatically assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a part of the answer there : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/default-category-for-a-custom-post-type. If you follow that logic :

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $idOfAllTheCategoriesInAnArray,'category');
```

and use the appropriate hook (`save_post` for example), then you can even automate this. Post here if you find better !